# When adding <img> to my code .svg not appearing

Tags: html, image, svg, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode and I am trying to add an .svg file to my project but it is not appearing on the Live Server. I used the same code just different file name as the other assets and it the file just will not appear.

Here is the JSFiddle of my project: https://jsfiddle.net/sillybrownboy/netgLq94/14/

```
 '''

<img class="about_1"
src="images/about_icon.svg">
'''
```

I obviously had to host my .svg files and .png files in order to get it to work but I left the code for the "about_icon.svg" the same at the bottom of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would check path where the `about_icon.svg` image is being stored. On your JSFiddle code, all the images are showing an absolute path, where the `about_icon.svg` is showing a relative path, in relation to that specific web page. If the `about_icon.svg` image is being stored on a remote server, similar to the other images, then you want to change the `src` location for the `about_1` image to an absolute path, not a relative path.

Also, from my experience, I have forgotten to upload images or uploaded to a wrong location on the server, and have wondered why they weren't displaying.